# Is there a way to hot reload local module in React app created with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have a project set up like this:

```
server/
client/
  src/
shared/
  my-module/
    index.ts
```

where `server` is a node Express app and `client` is a React + TypeScript app bootstrapped with `create-react-app`. I have some code that I want to share between the 2 apps, but React does not allow me to import modules outside of src, so I created a local TS module under `shared/my-module` that I install in server and client.

My question is, when I have the React dev server running, is there a way to automatically build the local TS module & hot reload the module whenever I make changes to my-module? Similar to how a reload happens whenever I make changes to src in the React app. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem at the moment. Did you find a satisfying solution?

Comment: @Ni2Be I couldn't find a solution for `create-react-app`, so I migrated to `nextjs`. If this is the route you want to take, I would recommend looking into https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules

Comment: thx for the reply. We also decided that it's time to move away from create-react-app. We switched to vite and node workspaces. I hope I can give an update in future that this is a good solution, otherwise we will also consider nextjs :D